# fscanf format specifier into structs

Tags: c, struct, scanf, stdio, format-specifiers

I have a data format like the following:

```
22/March/2014
137 8
15 16 34 8 18
17/November/2014
106 8
22 29 30 9 6
20/November/2014
169 10
50 58 38 29 1
```

I am trying to use fscanf to get the contents of the file and place them into the following struct:

```
    struct date{

    //This is storing the date dd/month/yyyy.
    char* fullDate;

    // Number of foot and wheelchair passengers.
    int foot;
    int wheelchair;

    //number of infant, child, adult, senior and family tickets sold
    int infant;
    int child;
    int adult;
    int senior;
    int family;
};
```

So i tried the following:

```
struct date r[50];
    FILE* der = fopen("C:\\Users\\Def\\Downloads\\annual_sales_data_2014.txt","r");
    int i = 0;
    rewind(der);
    fscanf(der, "%s", r[i].fullDate);
    fscanf(der, "%d %d ", &r[i].foot, &r[i].wheelchair);
    fscanf(der, "%d %d %d %d",&r[i].infant, &r[i].child, &r[i].adult, &r[i].senior, &r[i].family);
    printf("%s\n%d %d\n%d %d %d %d %d\n\n", r[i].fullDate, r[i].foot, r[i].wheelchair, r[i].infant, r[i].child, r[i].adult, r[i].senior, r[i].family);

    fclose(der);
```

But i believe that fscanf is not being used right and i'm getting a bit confused by the documentation for format specifiers, I have also tried it this way.

```
    fscanf(der, "%s/%s/%s\n%d %d\n%d %d %d %d %d\n", r[i].day, r[i].month, , r[i].year, &r[i].foot, &r[i].wheelchair, &r[i].infant, &r[i].child, &r[i].adult, &r[i].senior, &r[i].family);
```

In the above example i also catered the struct to accept 3 char*'s for the day month and year. in the beginning of the format specifiers string. This didn't work either so i broke it down to a smaller format to see if i could diagnose the problem.

Even in the broken down example this

```
fscanf(der, "%s", r[i].fullDate);
```

even this breaks in the debugger and cant work out why.

Thanks.

Comment: When you  `fscanf` into a variable, you should give it it's address.

Comment: `r[i].fullDate` doesn't point to a determinate memory buffer capable of receiving data, yet you pass its undefined-value as gospel to `fscanf` for population. Your code invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: In your first attempt, the last `scanf()` needs one more `%d`.  Otherwise it should work, except that you need to allocate memory for the `fullDate` member of each of the structs first (and should add an appropriate width to the `%s` to prevent overruns).

Comment: "`//This is storing the date dd/month/yyyy.
    char* fullDate;`" - **NO** It stores a pointer to `char` - A pointer is not an array!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot parse the date with `fscanf(der, "%s", r[i].fullDate);` because `fulldate` is an uninitialized pointer.  You are supposed to pass the address of an array for the `%s` format. Put an array in the structure instead of a pointer, such as `char fullDate[30];` and use `fscanf(der, "%29s", r[i].fullDate);`

Note that you can parse the date components directly with:

```
char monthName[16];
int day, year;

if (fscanf("%d/%15[^ /]/%d", &day, monthName, &year) == 3) {
    /* Date parsed correctly */
} else {
    /* At least one field missing, bail out */
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for your response, they are all appreciated :) This guy hit the nail on the head, even answered a question i was meant to ask but forgot :D. now I know how to parse the date, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

`fullDate` must be initialized before using. The simplest way is:

```
r[i].fullDate = malloc(whatever_size_you_need);
```

or you may even declare it as an array to avoid extra initialization:

```
struct date{

    //This is storing the date dd/month/yyyy.
    char fullDate[proper_size];

    // ...
};
```

Of course you must ensure somehow that read string will fit into buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You say you believe that `fscanf` is not being used right, and that is true. This line

```
fscanf(der, "%d %d %d %d", &r[i].infant, &r[i].child, &r[i].adult, &r[i].senior, &r[i].family);
```

is passing arguments for the 5 fields you want to fill, but it only has 4 format format specifiers. Try this:

```
fscanf(der, "%d %d %d %d %d", &r[i].infant, &r[i].child, &r[i].adult, &r[i].senior, &r[i].family);
```

In addition, you should always check the data fields were read properly. The return value from `fscanf` would have told you that only 4 items were read.